# What is the difference between wcsncpy and wcscpy_s?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Is there any practical difference between using `wcscpy_s` and using `wcsncpy`? The only difference seems to be the order of parameters and return value:

```
errno_t wcscpy_s(wchar_t *strDestination,
                 size_t numberOfElements,
                 const wchar_t *strSource);

wchar_t *wcsncpy(wchar_t *strDest,
                 const wchar_t *strSource,
                 size_t count );
```

And if there is no practical difference, why did Microsoft need to add `wcscpy_s` to Visual Studio, when `wcsncpy` was already available and a standard function?

Is it OK to replace `wcscpy_s` to `wcsncpy` when porting from Visual Studio to gcc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These two functions do not have the same behavior.

From [the MSDN documentation of `wcscpy_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx):

> Upon successful execution, the destination string will always be null terminated.

From the specification of `wcsncpy` (C11 7.29.4.2.2/1-3):

> ```
> #include <wchar.h>
> wchar_t *wcsncpy(wchar_t * restrict s1,
>     const wchar_t * restrict s2,
>     size_t n);
> ```
>
> The `wcsncpy` function copies not more than `n` wide characters (those that follow a null
>   wide character are not copied) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the array pointed to by
>   `s1`.
>
> If the array pointed to by `s2` is a wide string that is shorter than `n` wide characters, null wide characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by `s1`, until `n` wide characters in all have been written

and the footnote (#346):

> Thus, if there is no null wide character in the first `n` wide characters of the array pointed to by `s2`, the result will not be null-terminated.

Note that `strncpy` and `wcsncpy` are not designed for use with null-terminated strings.  They are designed for use with null-padded, fixed-width strings.

Comment: I'll also note that Visual Studio includes the sources for the CRT.  If you are curious about how a particular function is implemented (or what the difference is between two functions is), you can take a look.

Answer (score 5):

Another difference (that just cost me a couple hours of staring at code, wondering what was going on) is that the wcscpy_s function will, by default, terminate the application if you're going to overrun the buffer.

I expected it to behave like one of the strncpy variants. That is not the case!

You can apparently change this behavior with the _set_invalid_parameter_handler function.

Answer (score 2):

`wcscpy_s` [is more secure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx), it can detect your error and trigger the [Invalid Parameter Handler Routine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx). For handling such errors without causing crash, they have provided `_set_invalid_parameter_handler`.

Answer (score 0):

The functions with the appended _s are functions whoch are more secure. Usually, the functions not conating the trailing _s will be marked as "deprecated" by VS2012 for example. You will get a warning. For additional information: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx) has plenty of information on this.

Comment: Thanks, but in what way is `wcscpy_s` more secure than `wcsncpy`, when they both accept the destination buffer's capacity?

Comment: I believe it is not about the security of the user/developer, but rather the security on the C-Runtime.